# Creating a column based on existing values and applying logics to some - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I don't really know what I had to write for the title, as I can not word it out in a single sentence - apologies in advance.

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need it to look like so:

[image]

Look at my code:

```
select 
    name,
    [sequence] = case
                    when right(left(name, 4), 1) = 'A'
                       then step
                    when right(left(name, 4), 1) = 'B'
                       then -- I'm stuck here. The logic needs to be the maximum of step when right(left(name, 4), 1) was A + step when it was B
                 end,
    value
from
    table 1
where 
    name like 'AM13%'
order by 
    sequence asc
```

I'm trying to apply the logic that if the first character after "AM13" was "A", then to bring the step, however if it was B, then add the step to the maximum of A and so on. so instead of having 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2 i would have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I am so stuck!

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Overcomplicated? Does not `right(left(name, 4), 1)` simply mean `substring(@x, 4, 1)`? And perhaps you meant to refer to the 5th character (A in first row) rather than 4th (3 in first row)?

Comment: oh apologies, you are right. and the substring is awesome, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For this sample data, wouldn't `row_number()` just work?

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over(order by name, step) as sequence
from mytable t
order by name, step
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! my actual query is super long and it contains many joins, so im worried about the expand-ability of this method. i thought about using variables to capture the maximum of step when the case was pointing to A, to use it in B, but couldn't.

Comment: @P.MAJ: you can use `row_number()` in your existing query, this is perfectly fine. Just put in the the `select` clause of your query.

Comment: unfortunately i ran into a problem. if i take out the "where" clause, and the 500th row is where AM13 starts, then the sequence would be 500 to 509. i need every AM## to start with 1.

Comment: could be resolved by a function or stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

so ok, I found a solution, and it works.. to a degree:

```
select 
    t1.name,
    [sequence] = case
                        when substring(t1.name, 5, 1) = 'A'
                            then t1.step
                        when substring(t1.name, 5, 1) = 'B'
                            then (select
                                      count(t2.name) --or max(t2.name)
                                  from table 1 as t2
                                  where t2.name like concat(LEFT(t1.name, 4), 'A%')) + t1.step
                        else t1.step
                 end,
    value
from
    table 1 as t1
/*where 
    name like 'AM13%'*/
order by 
    sequence asc
```